# google app engine java web application doesn't go to welcome-file page in production

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, dev-to-production

I have google app engine java web application with Start.jsp page specified as welcome-file in web.xml. When I run it on development machine in Eclipse IDE it goes to Start.jsp page, but in production in Google cloud I get 404 and have to specify Start.jsp explicitly in url. Also and redirects to "/" work fine on development box but return 404 in production.

Comment: check if you might have some extra forward slash "/" in your redirection URL.

Comment: Nope, I have just one "/", and it works on dev server fine

Comment: You might have the same in your configuration, as I have also faced the same problem and struggled for 3 days, as everything was working fine on dev, but on production everything stopped working because on an extra "/" forward slash in my configuration file.